# How to initialize a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am working on a C++ program, and I need to initialize a vector of pointers. I know how to initialize a vector, but if someone could show me how to initialize it as a vector filled with pointers that would be great!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258871/how-to-use-find-algorithm-with-a-vector-of-pointers-to-objects-in-c to see vectors in use.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817263/is-it-possible-to-create-a-vector-of-pointers

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A zero-size vector of pointers:

```
std::vector<int*> empty;
```

A vector of NULL pointers:

```
std::vector<int*> nulled(10);
```

A vector of pointers to newly allocated objects (not really initialization though):

```
std::vector<int*> stuff;
stuff.reserve(10);
for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    stuff.push_back(new int(i));
```

Initializing a vector of pointers to newly allocated objects (needs C++11):

```
std::vector<int*> widgets{ new int(0), new int(1), new int(17) };
```

A smarter version of #3:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> stuff;
stuff.reserve(10);
for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    stuff.emplace_back(new int(i));
```

Comment: Boo for exception unsafety! :-)

Comment: `emplace_back` doesn't buy you anything with scalar types such as pointers.

Comment: @FredOverflow:  `unique_ptr`'s constructor is explicit, so you either need to use `emplace_back` or `stuff.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(i)));`.  Between the two, `emplace_back` is much cleaner.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I stand corrected.